# Get absolute path to directory containing current FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

In [Apache FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/), how can I get the absolute path to the directory containing the current `.ftl` file?

For example, if I was processing the file `/path/to/template.ftl`, then I'm searching for a way to get `/path/to` inside of `/path/to/template.ftl`.

I've tried `.current_template_name` [and friends](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_specvar.html), but these really only contain the name of the file, not its absolute path (from which I could get the parent directory). I've also tried [absolute_template_name](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_absolute_template_name), but this just seems to prepend the name with a `/` to make the path seem absolute, but it does not resolve to the real absolute path.

Background: I'm templatizing Asciidoc files with with Freemarker, and the Asciidoc files must include other Asciidoc files which reside below the original directory of the `.flt` file, so they must not be searched relative to the temporarily "expanded" Asciidoc file.

Comment: In my particular case I was able to solve the matter by not letting Asciidoc resolve the include, but already let FreeMarker inline the included Asciidoc files. That way, I do not need to generate the absolute path for the Asciidoc include in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template paths that templates use are always virtual, and resolved by the `TemplateLoader` object set in the `Configuration`. `TemplateLoader` is just an interface, has multiple implementations, and so is a black box for FreeMarker. The actual location of the template can be inside a jar file, or even in the database table, so in general a template has no path on the file system.

Normally, you set up the `TemplateLoader` so that it can access all the templates you need. Then you don't need any tricks, and just use template paths.

Another possibility is to use a `FileTemplateLoader` that uses the root directory as base directory. This of course would be a bad idea for most applications (especially for web applications, for security reasons).

Comment: "or even in the database table"... if that's the case, how comes `.current_template_name` is available to get the file name of the template?

Comment: Because template paths are virtual, and not filesystem paths. A `TemplateLoader` can map a such virtual path to a database table row for example. (Like maybe the table has a path column, and a content column.)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read the explanation in the accepted answer, because it is most likely that you need something else. Having said that, you can dive deep in the inner workings of freemarker using reflection. The following code gets the absolute path for a given templateName.

```
  private String getAbsolutePath(String inputFilePath, Configuration freeMarkerConfiguration) {
    String absolutePath = null;
    try {
      TemplateCache templateCache = getField(freeMarkerConfiguration, "cache", TemplateCache.class);
      Locale locale = freeMarkerConfiguration.getLocale();
      TemplateLookupResult lookup = callMethod(templateCache, "lookupTemplate", TemplateLookupResult.class, new Object[] {inputFilePath, locale, null});
      Object templateSource = callMethod(lookup, "getTemplateSource", Object.class, new Object[] {});
      File source = getField(templateSource, "source", File.class);
      absolutePath = source.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return absolutePath;
  }

  private <T> T callMethod(Object source, String methodName, Class<T> claz, Object[] methodInput)
      throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?>[] inputTypes = Arrays.asList(methodInput).stream().map(t -> t == null ? Object.class : t.getClass()).toArray(Class[]::new);
    return callMethod(source, methodName, claz, methodInput, inputTypes);
  }

  private <T> T callMethod(Object source, String methodName, Class<T> claz, Object[] methodInput, Class<?>[] inputTypes)
      throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Method method = source.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, inputTypes);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    Object result = method.invoke(source, methodInput);
    return claz.cast(result);
  }

  private <T> T getField(Object source, String fieldName, Class<T> claz)
      throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
    Field field = source.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object value = field.get(source);
    return claz.cast(value);
  }
```